# How to upgrade my Java web application to work with PHP

Tags: java, php, jquery, ajax, web-applications

I am new to Java web application development. I recently built a Java web application on my own and I have Tomcat server installed for the same. Recently I have learned Javascript, Jquery and then i learnt JSON and AJAX.

While I learn that with the help of JQuery and AJAX I can dynamically update my webpage.So i learnt some basics of PHP as well. But I don't understand where to place my PHP file !

I also read in the internet that apache server is better suited for executing PHP files. Now I have my java app all set with Tomcat server. I want to learn/make use of `Jquery-AJAX-PHP` functionality but stuck without knowing how to proceed further. Can anyone please advice me how to proceed with simple and detailed steps?

What all i want is to make a AJAX call from Java script to a PHP file and then echo a `Hello`.

Comment: Your web server needs to be able to execute PHP scripts.  Very few Java-based web servers can do that.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen okay I understand your point . Now if i want my AJAX to call PHP and in turn PHP to call database what should i do ? A separate server for handling PHP files ? Consider i have to update some part of my webpage with information from a database. JQuery or Ajax cannot do it i believe . In such a case i need PHP . Correct me if i am wrong !

Comment: You can do anything in Java you can do in PHP.   I would suggest you go for understanding what happens in the browser first and how requests go back to the webserver for information etc.   Java can talk to a database as well as PHP can.

Comment: @thorbjorn I very well know that java can talk with database.  But once a page loads and if we want to update some part of the database without refreshing the page I believe we need something beyond java

Comment: No.  Have a look at Java Server Faces which can do this.